# ReactJS - Handle POST requests using react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is there a way to handle `POST` requests using the `react-router-dom` (npm) library?

Why? The payment gateway will redirect the user, who successfully payed, back to the platform. I can use a `GET` or `POST` request to transfer data with the redirection page. But I don't like having the data visible in the URL. Other options are always welcome, I'm using a REST API (Node.JS, Express) and a website/dashboard (ReactJS)

Comment: To clarify a bit, are you trying to `POST` data to your browser?

Comment: @imjared Yes, I'm trying to receive data not via the url parameters but some 'secret' way that nobody can see it.

Comment: Why not handle the POST in your node server?

Comment: Because it's a visual response for the user that the payment was successful. I need data from the payment so I can't just show a default page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get what you're after but you can't `POST` to the browser. If you're uncomfortable passing data as `GET` params in a URL, you could:

1. store data in LocalStorage when user submits
2. deliver server-rendered, static HTML upon redirect that contains purchase information
3. asynchronously get user's purchase data upon page load with AJAX or `fetch()` (or your favorite data-grabbing util).

Since you're in a React world, I'd recommend the third option here. How to fetch data, build an API endpoint, store data, then display it goes *well* beyond the scope of this question so I'd suggest some Googling. Here's a starting point: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-api-calls-with-react-and-axios--cms-21027

Comment: Third option seems perfect! Thanks for giving your insights on this topic :)

Comment: Hello Sir i have the same Situation But I have react app with PHP Backend which are communicating using GraphQL how to handle it?

Answer (score 5):

You can handle the POST request on your express server then redirect to a static page of your app :

```
app.post('/payment_webhook', (req, res) => {
    const paymentOk = req.body.payment // handle POST data
    if (paymentOk) {
        res.redirect('http://app.com/payment_success');
    } else {
        res.redirect('http://app.com/payment_failed');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but this doesn't solve the problem that I want to display the user's payment information.

Comment: Maybe too late but if paymentOk, backend might save payment data to db first and redirect link would be '..../payment_success&id={savedPaymentId}', then frontend payment_success page as soon as it loads would send a get request to fetch the payment data by using id param in the url.

Answer (score 1):

I was discussing the same with a friend and so far we saw 2 ways of doing this:

1. let the payment gateway `return_url` be an endpoint of the backend API (rails api), which will do the commit to the payment gateway (and probably updating the order in the BD), and then it will do a redirect back to your frontend app
2. store the gateway trasaction token on the order object in the DB, and let the payment gateway `return_url` to return to a dynamic order url, therefore, react will now which order should render, then asynchronously ask the backend (rails service) to extract the token from the order object and do the commit (confirmation) and update it's status and return the order object back to react, then react can now show if the order was successful or not.

we opted for option #2, since I feel that the frontend (react) shall be the main communication gateway to our system, and the only one communicating to the backend shall be the frontend.

UPDATE: option #2 did not work since you cant do POST to a react-app therefore, we make the return_url to be dynamic, and we immediately redirect to the frontend with a url with the order_id as query param, then, the frontend when tries to load the order, in the backend we do the payment gatway confirmation, update the order object and return the updated order object to the frontend

Comment: Exactly, all communication between machines (non-user) should go via a REST API or something similar. A token save is a MUST for security reasons, but you also pointed that out :)

Comment: @Michiel thanks for your insight, I added an update for future readers, thanks again

Comment: This is a great response, definitely having the return url pointed at the backend is the right approach in this case